# How do I set the priorities for a Bootswatch theme on my Rails site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, bootswatch

I was using the standard 'bootstrap-sass' gem to add Bootstrap to my site. I decided I wanted to replace the standard styles, so I downloaded a CSS file (cerulean.css) from Bootswatch.com and placed it in my stylesheets folder. I then included it in application.css. The issue is that many of its styles seem to be overridden by default Bootstrap's. For example, the navbar color is still black (except a tiny bit in the corner). I assume this is because the gradients have priority over cerulean's colors. How do I set Cerulean.css as the higher-priority?

Comment: You have to load the new file `cerulean.css` after the line that loads the Bootstrap CSS. At least in theory, that's all there's to it.